# Total number of minutes so far since midnight

Tags: javascript

How would I get the total number of minutes in the day so far since midnight?

I.e. if it was 12:37am, I would want 37, if it was 1:41am, I would want 101, or if it 12:20pm, it would return int 740 (740 total minutes that day so far).

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Or are you expecting us just to do all the work for you?

Comment: make one date with the time you want and one with the time at midnight, subtract them and convert the milliseconds to minutes OR use a library like moment.js

Comment: This question really shows a serious lack of research or effort put in to resolve issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();

var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var hours = date.getHours();

var result = (60 * hours) + minutes;

console.log(result);
```

See [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on MDN for further information, like what the heck `getMinutes()` actually does.

For future questions, please consider consulting MDN or a similiar resource first.

Comment: Yup. May be the case. If he is truly eager to learn something new, though, I hopefully shed some light on him. I had hard times understanding something, too, and I wished for a simple and clear answer instead of rantings about rules. And if I just did his homework, who has been harmed?

Comment: *If he is truly eager to learn* he should read a tutorial, and put some effort on it... Then, when he gets stuck into some **specific problem** he can address to SO for help...

Comment: I agree with you that one should at least *try* to solve an issue by oneself. But that's because this is the most effective way of learning. If he c&p's this and is asked question on what the script is actual doing, he will find that this wasn't the best idea. I'll add some link to MDN, though. No offense, I see your point. I just think the situation isn't *that* bad.

Answer (score 0):

Just times the amount of `.getHours()` by 60 then add the `.getMinutes()` method for a Date object.

```
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var totalMinutes = (hours*60) + minutes
```